# Formula for lines that can be drawn using $n$ points

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Please help me!
How many lines can be drawn using $6$ points? Each line is made by connecting $2$ points.

Comment: You need to know more about the points in order to answer this question precisely. For example all 6 points could be on the same line and so you can only make one line with the 6 points.

Comment: What have you tried? (How many pairs of points do you have? How many lines can you draw at most between each pair of points?)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where the points are. If no three are on a line, then any two determine a line, so the answer is the number of ways to choose two things from six. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: that is the only info stated on the question. but the choices are a.)9, B.) 12 c.) 15 d.) 18 e.) 26

Comment: I'm not sure you read past the first sentence of my answer. I'm not asking you for information on the question; I'm asking whether you are familiar with the number of ways to choose two things from six.